# Defining better hosting infra

Tags: magento-1.7, server-setup

How can I determine if I should go with LAMP or LEMP (Apache or Nginx)? Considering Magento's software requirements list both.

Should I prefer SSD storage or more RAM?

Comment: I prefer digitalocean.

Comment: Do you recommend the LEMP or LAMP stack? Please, post an answer so I can +1 you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it has nothing to do with Magento development.

Comment: Edited the question. Don't we have infra tags? I believe this SO site is not only about source code.

Comment: No it is not, but the question is too broad to answer without details about your goal. How much visitors, how much products, configurables, simples, orders/day, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Buddy Most of PHP Servers are LAMP(Linux Apache Mysql PHP). So I definitely recommended you. also give some suggestion like if your site contain large amount of images in future then buy unlimited hosting service.

If you have good amount of money then you can also prefer to buy a dedicated host form your hosting providers.